# The following packages have unmet dependencies after installing .deb file

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dependencies, deb

I was trying to learn to create and use .deb file. I added those libs as dependencies to that .deb file under DEBIAN/control file

```
Package: mydeb
Version: 1.0-1
Section: base
Priority: optional
Architecture: amd64
Depends: ipython (>= 2.4.1-1), decorator (>= 4.0.10), cycler (>= 0.10.0), Cython (>= 0.25.1), dask (>= 0.12.0), imageio (>= 1.6), matplotlib (>= 1.5.3), networkx (>= 1.11), numpy (>= 1.11.2), Pillow (>= 3.4.2), pip (>= 9.0.1), pyglet (>= 1.2.4), pymongo (>= 3.4.0), pyparsing (>= 2.1.10), python-dateutil (>= 2.6.0), pytz (>= 2016.7), requests (>= 2.12.1), scikit-image (>= 0.12.3), scipy (>= 0.18.1), setuptools (>= 28.8.0), six (>= 1.10.0), toolz (>= 0.8.0), wheel (>= 0.30.0a0)         
Maintainer: xxx
Description: xxx
```

but after I installed that sample .deb file, I have started to see that error during these commands

```
sudo apt-get update & upgrade
```

The errors, I am getting are

```
username@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
                   <my deb file > : Depends: decorator (>= 4.0.10) but it is not installable
                   Depends: cycler (>= 0.10.0) but it is not installable
                   Depends: cython (>= 0.25.1) but 0.23.4-0ubuntu5 is installed
                   Depends: dask (>= 0.12.0) but it is not installable
                   Depends: imageio (>= 1.6) but it is not installable
                   Depends: matplotlib (>= 1.5.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: networkx (>= 1.11) but it is not installable
                   Depends: numpy (>= 1.11.2) but it is not installable
                   Depends: pillow (>= 3.4.2) but it is not installable
                   Depends: pip (>= 9.0.1) but it is not installable
                   Depends: pyglet (>= 1.2.4) but it is not installable
                   Depends: pymongo (>= 3.4.0) but it is not installable
                   Depends: pyparsing (>= 2.1.10) but it is not installable
                   Depends: python-dateutil (>= 2.6.0) but 2.4.2-1 is installed
                   Depends: pytz (>= 2016.7) but it is not installable
                   Depends: requests (>= 2.12.1) but it is not installable
                   Depends: scikit-image (>= 0.12.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: scipy (>= 0.18.1) but it is not installable
                   Depends: setuptools (>= 28.8.0) but it is not installable
                   Depends: six (>= 1.10.0) but it is not installable
                   Depends: toolz (>= 0.8.0) but it is not installable
                   Depends: wheel (>= 0.30.0a0) but it is not installable
```

somehow those libs integrate themselves to package manager and that is started to become problem after installing my .deb package. Those libs are already installed on my system.

How do I reset my package manager or overcome this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Did you run `sudo 'apt-get -f install` as recommended by `apt`?

Comment: yes, you are right.somehow I ignored the recommendation. Now everything working good. But have a question how an external .deb package is able to broke my package manager? Those libs are already installed on my system. Thank you!

Comment: `deb` file will only break it if the `deb` file your created isn't done right. Not an expert on this but please run these `deb` or test them in a `virtual machine` before actually doing them in your live system. That's how to learn else you will always get into trouble.

Comment: Got you, that package still needs to be improved. Thank you for the explanation!  @George

Comment: Is this on Ubuntu 16.04 ? The first one "cycler" already cannot be found with that name here : ~ $ apt-cache search cycler
bicyclerepair - A refactoring tool for python
python-cycler - composable kwarg iterator (Python 2)
python3-cycler - composable kwarg iterator (Python 3)

Comment: Yes that's on Ubuntu 16.04. when I did pip list, I saw it was written like that but I think, it is something comes as default libs of the virtual environment of the python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

this command is solved the problem! Thank you @George